# quill classes in quill.root.innerHTML is not working

Tags: angular, quill, text-align

I'm using quill in angular4 and I have a problem. I want to save a quill text in the database and I'm using `quill.root.innerHTML` to save it. but when I want to show the text, it only applies the tags that are generated, like  or  but the classes like `class="ql-direction-rtl ql-align-center"` or `class="ql-size-large"` are not applying on the text.
 here are codes:

html:

```
<select class="ql-align">
                <option selected=""></option>
                <option value="center"></option>
                <option value="right"></option>
                <option value="justify"></option>
              </select>
```

ts

```
//use to get text from db
this.quill.root.innerHTML = mail.mail.rows[0].content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, use the `quill.root.innerHTML` only to retrieve the html generated by [quill](/questions/tagged/quill)

To load text, load it first in an HTML element, and then create a new instance of the Quill object:

```
<div ng-bind-html="quillEditor" id="myQuillEditor"> //Your Editor element </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.quillEditor= mail.mail.rows[0].content;

[...]

$scope.init = function(){

    new Quill('#myQuillEditor');

}
```

Quill will automatically render your objects and apply style

Comment: the HTML codes that I used are generated from my quill, and would you please tell me how should I do it in angular 4?? and what do you mean by "editor element" ??